# Unable to access hard drive

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive

I am receiving the message shown below when trying to access a hard drive on my PC! Can anyone help me with simple instructions to recover the drive? thanks you

```
Unable to access “DATAPART1”

Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/james/DATAPART1: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/james/DATAPART1"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

Answer (score 0):

I/O error very often means a hardware failure. If it's not hardware then more than likely you will need to reformat or/and repartition the drive. So probably try `gparted` and `fdisk`. Also you can try to boot up from Live CD to narrow the problem down.